# iPad mini and 4th generation machine id

Tags: ipad, ipad-mini

Anyone know the machine IDs for these new devices? For example the 3rd generation iPad could be iPad3,1 iPad3,2, iPad3,5 iPad3,6 depending on the model. I'm finding the string with this

```
struct utsname systemInfo;
uname(&systemInfo);
NSString *dev = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: No one outside Apple will know this yet. You'll need to wait until next Friday when the first units get delivered.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping some review units were out and about or it leaked into some plist, but after searching high and low I think you're right we  may just have to wait

Comment: This page shows that iPad3,4 is being used for at least one of the devices. This is going to be confusing if 3,1-2-5-6 are 3rd generation and 3,4-? are 4th generation (I'm guessing that there are different IDs for the different wifi/lte versions). Still no id on the mini yet, probably will show up before Friday though. http://www.primatelabs.com/blog/2012/10/early-ipad-4th-generation-benchmarks/

Comment: Anybody have the new iPad Air or iPad Mini Retina IDs yet?

Answer (score 7):

I got a new Ipad 4th Wifi, the machine model is `iPad3,4`

Also, Ipad mini Wifi is `iPad2,5`

**Edited**

On Mid-November will be launch the rest of the new Ipad models: (as Ipad 3th gen)

- `iPad3,5` for iPad 4th gen GSM
- `iPad3,6` for iPad 4th gen CDMA
- `iPad2,6` for Ipad mini Wifi GSM
- `iPad2,7` for Ipad mini Wifi CDMA

Comment: Those have been confirmed - http://www.macrumors.com/2012/11/08/apple-posts-ios-6-0-1-downloads-for-cellular-capable-ipad-mini-and-fourth-generation-ipad/

Comment: New iPad Air and iPad Mini retina?

Answer (score -2):

Just got my iPad mini. "iPad2,5"
UIDevice model is just "iPad". I suspect the larger iPad 2 will be phased out since it does not have the lighting port, and the new iPad mini Retina will be iPad2,6

Comment: Thanks. Though I think 2,6 and 2,7 will most likely be the 4G versions, not a future retina model

Comment: There is only 3 values for `[UIDevice currentDevice].model` you can see them in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411075/uidevice-currentdevice-model-possible-values/16567993#16567993)