# What are the new device models for iPad 4th gen and Ipad mini?

Tags: ios, ipad, ipad-mini

I am trying to figure out which device models are new iPad 4th & iPad mini.

I got a new Ipad 4th Wifi, the model is `iPad3,4`. Anyone knows the Ipad 4th gen or iPad mini?

my guess for the rest of the Ipad models is: (as Ipad 3th gen)

- `iPad3,5`     for iPad 4th gen GSM
- `iPad3,6`     for iPad 4th gen CDMA

**UPDATE**

Ipad mini Wifi is `iPad2,5`

GSM & CDMA?

Comment: tefeta this not the right platform for this question here we discuss the issues coming in the development area we are not here to discuss like any Tech Giant forum did.

Comment: I think this is a development issue, because in the app I am working on there is a label formated with the device model.  
    `size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *model = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", model, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *sDeviceModel = @(model);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPad mini and 4th generation machine id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088889/ipad-mini-and-4th-generation-machine-id)