# UIDevice currentDevice model possible values

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

What are all the possible values returned by `[[UIDevice currentDevice] model];`? It isn't  [documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html).

Answer (score 42):

The possible vales are `iPod touch`, `iPhone`, `iPhone Simulator`, `iPad`, `iPad Simulator`

If you want to know which hardware `iOS` is ruining on like `iPhone3`, `iPhone4`, `iPhone5` etc below is the code for that

---

**NOTE:** The below code may not contain all device's string, I'm with other guys are maintaining the same code on **GitHub** so please take the latest code from there

Objective-C : [GitHub/DeviceUtil](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/DeviceUtil)

Swift : [GitHub/DeviceGuru](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/DeviceGuru)

---

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

- (NSString*)hardwareDescription {
    NSString *hardware = [self hardwareString];
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"]) return @"iPhone 2G";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"]) return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"]) return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"]) return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"]) return @"iPhone 5";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"]) return @"iPodTouch 1G";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"]) return @"iPodTouch 2G";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"]) return @"iPad";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"]) return @"iPad Mini";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"]) return @"iPad Air WIFI";
    //there are lots of other strings too, checkout the github repo
    //link is given at the top of this answer

    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"i386"]) return @"Simulator";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"x86_64"]) return @"Simulator";

    return nil;
}

- (NSString*)hardwareString {
    size_t size = 100;
    char *hw_machine = malloc(size);
    int name[] = {CTL_HW,HW_MACHINE};
    sysctl(name, 2, hw_machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *hardware = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:hw_machine];
    free(hw_machine);
    return hardware;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why was this accepted. It doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: It looks to me like it did, but in a roundabout way.

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore, in iOS 6.1 this func is not work at perfectly. In 1 case from 3, then can return a other value

Comment: @CReaTuS Have you tried open project of mine here https://github.com/rathore619/UIDevice-Hardware

Comment: @InderKumarRathore. Thanks, in this link, func **hardwareString** is changed. Will try =)

Comment: @InderKumarRathore It works, please update your answer with new function =)

Comment: @CReaTuS I have updated my answer. And please share new string if you found any for new hardware so that the above project remains updated. :)

Comment: @InderKumarRathore hardware was iPad3,1, but function will return as nil string, what so interest, in 1 case from 3. And sure, if i will found a new values, i will let u know

Comment: iPhone5c and iPhone5s returns are iPhone6,1 and iPhone6,2

Comment: @CReaTuS somebody has pushed the code in git for iPhone 5c and iPhone 5s

Comment: It would be really nice to be able to return "isSimulator" as well as the simulated device model.

Comment: Alex I have posted open source project please help youself as well as us too

Comment: for iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus code is: iPhone7,2 and iPhone7,1

Comment: Thanks @CReaTuS I will add this to git hub project.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the amazing answer. And my question is will apple reject my app if I use this code ?

Comment: @ThilinaCháminHewagama Whatever methods I have used in this are well documented and hence apple won't have any issues with it. You can use it without any fear.

Comment: This is an excellent answer to a completely unrelated question.  What the op asked was which values are returned specifically from UIDevice.currentDevice().model.  What has been answered and discussed here is a completely unrelated way of getting information about the current device (which is great, but in no way an answer to the question).

Comment: oops for iphone 6 and 6 plus is there a different model number for CDMA devices ?

Answer (score 24):

I just did a test on iPod Touch, iPhone, Phone Retina, iPhone 5, iPad, iPad Retina and iPad Mini. So this is my conclusion:

```
iPod touch
iPhone
iPad
```

On simulators - this could be useful if you're a developer working on features that sometimes do not work at all on simulators - you'll get these values:

```
iPhone Simulator
iPad Simulator
```

Comment: Ah, the actual answer to the posted question!  Thanks.  I was specifically wondering if the iPad Mini would be indicated and didn't have one handy (and it's not supported in the XCode simulator), and this answered that.

Comment: Anyone know the values for AppleTV?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best answer to explain(something which wasn't written here)
Is to say that the value itself is a String value.
and the possible answers are string e.g: "iPhone","iPad" and etc..

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers are extendable for new model numbers. Here is an enumeration:

```
public enum DeviceType {
 case iPad(String?)
 case iPhone(String?)
 case simulator(String?)
 case appleTV(String?)
 case unknown
}
```

And Extension I wrote that I think is a little cleaner and a little more extendable for when new model number come out.

```
extension UIDevice {
    public static func getDevice() -> DeviceType {
        var info = utsname()
        uname(&info)
        let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: info.machine)
        let code = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
            guard let value = element.value as? Int8, value != 0 else {
                return identifier
            }
            return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
        }

        if code.lowercased().range(of: "ipad") != nil {
            if let range = code.lowercased().range(of: "ipad") {
                var mutate = code
                mutate.removeSubrange(range)
                return .iPad(mutate)
            }else{
                return .iPad(nil)
            }
        }else if code.lowercased().range(of: "iphone") != nil {
            if let range = code.lowercased().range(of: "iphone") {
                var mutate = code
                mutate.removeSubrange(range)
                return .iPhone(mutate)
            }else{
                return .iPhone(nil)
            }
        }else if code.lowercased().range(of: "i386") != nil || code.lowercased().range(of: "x86_64") != nil{
            return .simulator(code)
        }else if code.lowercased().range(of: "appletv") != nil {
            if let range = code.lowercased().range(of: "appletv") {
                var mutate = code
                mutate.removeSubrange(range)
                return .appleTV(mutate)
            }else{
                return .appleTV(nil)
            }
        }else{
            return .unknown
        }
    }
}
```