# What about iPod #define constants?

Tags: objective-c, ios6

When I try to define my constants here, I don't have any experiences about iPod:

```
#define isIPhone (![[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)] || [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

Can anyone know how to define the iPod models?

Comment: Did a rollback to the previous version of the question. Removing the code makes the question very broad.

Comment: This code was correct and it's writed in many other answers , I use it in my app pubblication without any problem, negative vote because it's unliked by one person may draw people into error.I try to delete all question without success.

Comment: You cannot delete the question because already has accepted answers, you can flag it for deletion if you want but don't remove the code because the question does not make sense without it.

Comment: I didnt know this flag. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the properties of [UIDevice currentDevice]:
[UIDevice reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html)

Branching based on resolution is definitely a bad idea.

See also: [UIDevice currentDevice model possible values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411075/uidevice-currentdevice-model-possible-values)

As this info is not going to change at run time, it is worth querying it once at the beginning, rather than calling the corresponding API at each specific conditional.