# How to check the specific iOS device the user is currently on

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

Using UIDevice seems to be incomplete. Whenever I try to use UIDevice().model, the output is just iPhone not iPhone 7 or whatever device the user is on.

```
let deviceName = UIDevice().model
let localizedName = UIDevice().localizedModel
```

Is there a way to tell what specific device the user is on in Swift?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14411113/1269509

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift/26962452#26962452

Comment: The other comments should help you out, but if you want a little less practical way of determining a phone size you can go by screen size. `if self.view.frame.height == blah && self.view.frame.width == bloop { let phoneSize = 3,4,5,6,etc }`