# Auto size UITextView for compatibility - Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm building an app and it seems like a simple issue but I can't for the life of me fix it.

On a screen, I have a large amount of text, provided through a UITextView. I would like it to essentially be static, without the scroll bar.

If I resize it manually in design view, and run it on an iPhone 7, the text fits nicely. However, if I run it on an iPhone 5c, it is too small due to the screen dimensions and then naturally reduces it and adds a scroll.

Is there a way I can tell the text to display it all and resize it accordingly, similar to the `SizeToFit()` command?

Comment: Use `UITextView.scrollEnabled = false`

Comment: By code: Enable Scroll, then setText, then read the contentSize (apply then some constraint according to it), then disable scroll?

Comment: Will that just not disable the scroll? Or will it automatically resize the UITextView output to fit for the dimensions?

Comment: It will have kind of `intrinsicContentSize` enabled. Which will act as you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the label if you don't want the scroll behavior.

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

This will fix the font size if label is not big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Assign constraints (tiny red lines in screenshot) to your UITextView then it will fit on all sizes correctly
[image]

And like @Orkhan Alikhanov said,  use UITextView.scrollEnabled = false – to disable scroll inside the textview

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to scroll why are you using a text field instead of a label? Either way, you can use the answer here [UIDevice currentDevice model possible values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411075/uidevice-currentdevice-model-possible-values) to determine what device you are using and then you can set the font size based on that information.

I suggest creating a function that does this calculation and then returns the font size so you can just call that whenever you are setting font.

Comment: If I use a label, it only stays on one line. I didn't realise you could have paragraphs on labels?

Comment: If you set the label lines = 0 it will adjust height to display all the content. You also need to make sure that your constraints allow it to grow and that it does not have exact height constraints.